# Creating tables within Crystal Reports

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I use Crystal Reports within C#.NET and I want to create multicolumn tables to present my data. Problem I have is that there is just no "table" component in the designer, I can only draw lines - and that's enought to create table.

However it seems to be very not flexible - creating tables just by lines - it leads to problem with adding new columns, because then you have to manually changes position of all the columns on the right from the one created?

How this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

You should experiment with cross-tabs (right click->insert cross-tab).  With a cross-tab, you can only show summarized data (i.e. no text), but it is very flexible with the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the things you have to live with, when using Crystal Reports.

However, if you drag a frame around all the items to the right of the position where you want to insert a new column, you can then drag and drop all of them almost as easily as if you were moving just one of them - this should at least reduce some of the work required.